# mailto-links and linebreaks in body

Tags: html

In a `mailto` link, I am trying to use linebreaks but I failed to do that! I have tried with `\n`, `/n` `<br>` and tried to search for ascii value of enter but I am not getting what am I looking for:

```
<a href="mailto:sadaf2605@gmail.com?subject=Your Subject&body=Hello, <br> I want your help!"> Mail me</a>
```

Can you guys help?

Comment: tried already! no luck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%0D%0A`:

```
body=Hello,%0D%0AI want your help!
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yCte6/1/*

---

More details of this can be found here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368

Comment: `%0D%0AI` is it ascii value of enter? certainly it does not look like that so what is it? :S

Comment: `%0D%0A` = `\r\n`. More details can be found here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368